# change file directory with php

Tags: php

How do I change the file location?

Now file is in "news" directory, how put file in "old_news"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by [rename](http://www.php.net/rename).

```
$success = rename("/news/file.txt", "/news_old/file.txt");

if ($success) 
 echo "Moved file!";
else
 echo "Failed to move file!";
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
<?php
$cmd = 'mv "/home/user/me/dir1" "/mnt/shares/nfsmount/dir2"';
exec($cmd, $output, $return_val);

if ($return_val == 0) {
   echo "success";
} else {
   echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need more information about the problem.  If you're trying to move the location of the PHP file, then just run:

```
mv file.php ../old_news/
```

If you're trying to change the working directory of the script, you can use the `chdir` function.

```
<?php
chdir("../new_directory/");
```

http://php.net/chdir